# Why is my translation different from theirs?

Tags: translation, word-choice, simplified-characters, sentence-structure

So, I was was reading something and they provided me a translation. Here's the first one:

> 我不想要你因为我变得消极
>   I won't want you to become pessimistic because of me.

Why didn't it translate to "I don't want you because I'll become pessimistic"?

Here's the second one:

> 从早安后的早餐,到晚餐后的晚安
>   From the Breakfast after good morning till after the dinner's good night

Why didn't it translate to "From morning after breakfast, till dinner after good night"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 我不想要你因为我变得消极。
   I don't want you to become demoralized because of me.

If you want the meaning 'because you make me depressed' try 2.

2. 我不想要你因为你让我变得消极 。
   I don't want you because you demoralize me.

In 3. I think you are just trying to apply the type of syntax you know to Chinese.

3. 从早安后的早餐,到晚餐后的晚安。
   From breakfast after Good Morning till Good Night after dinner.

If you take out the adjectives from 3., you have:
4. 从早餐到晚安
from breakfast till Good Evening

3. 从早安后的早餐,到晚餐后的晚安。

> Why didn't it translate to: From morning after breakfast, till dinner
>   after Good Night.

after breakfast is : 早餐后 but you have 'after Good Morning' = 早安后
after dinner is 晚餐后，after Good Evening is 晚安后

Answer (score 2):

> 我不想要 (I don't want)
>
> 你因为我变得消极 (you to become pessimistic because of me)

The problem here is you read '我不想要-- 你因为我变得消极' as '我不想要你, 因为我变得消极'

"我不想你因为我变得消极" would be a more clear sentence

> 从早安后的早餐,到晚餐后的晚安

Read it as "从 '(說了) 早安' 后的早餐, 到晚餐后的 '(說)晚安'"

> From the breakfast after (saying) good morning till after the dinner's (saying) good night

The time is between **breakfast** (which was after saying good morning) and **saying good night** (which was after the dinner)

*說了 and 說 are omitted*